# Reduce method in Reducer class is not executing

Tags: java, mapreduce

In the below code,inside reducer class reduce method is not executing. please help me.In my reduce method i want to write output in multiple files. so i have used multipleoutputs.

```
public class DataValidation {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        int flag = 1;
        boolean result;
        private HashMap<String, FileConfig> fileConfigMaps = new HashMap<String,             FileConfig>();
        private HashMap<String, List<LineValidator>> mapOfValidators = new HashMap<String, List<LineValidator>>();
        private HashMap<String, List<Processor>> mapOfProcessors = new HashMap<String, List<Processor>>();

        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("configure inside map class");
            ConfigurationParser parser = new ConfigurationParser();
            Config config = parser.parse(new Configuration());
            List<FileConfig> file = config.getFiles();
            for (FileConfig f : file) {
                try {
                    fileConfigMaps.put(f.getName(), f);
                    System.out.println("quotes in" + f.isQuotes());
                    System.out.println("file from xml : " + f.getName());
                    ValidationBuilder builder = new ValidationBuilder();
                    // ProcessorBuilder constructor = new ProcessorBuilder();
                    List<LineValidator> validators;
                    validators = builder.build(f);
                    // List<Processor> processors = constructor.build(f);
                    mapOfValidators.put(f.getName(), validators);
                    // mapOfProcessors.put(f.getName(),processors);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // String filename = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath()
            // .getName();
            FileSplit fs = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
            String fileName = fs.getPath().getName();
            System.out.println("filename : " + fileName);
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] csvDataArray = null;
            List<LineValidator> lvs = mapOfValidators.get(fileName);
            flag = 1;
            csvDataArray = line.split(",", -1);
            FileConfig fc = fileConfigMaps.get(fileName);
            System.out.println("filename inside fileconfig " + fc.getName());
            System.out.println("quote values" + fc.isQuotes());
            if (fc.isQuotes()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < csvDataArray.length; i++) {
                    csvDataArray[i] = csvDataArray[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
                }
            }
            for (LineValidator lv : lvs) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    result = lv.validate(csvDataArray, fileName);
                    if (result == false) {
                        String write = line + "," + lv.getFailureDesc();
                        System.out.println("write" + write);
                        System.out.println("key" + new Text(fileName));
                        // output.collect(new Text(filename), new Text(write));

                        context.write(new Text(fileName), new Text(write));

                        flag = 0;
                        if (lv.stopValidation(csvDataArray) == true) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        protected void cleanup(Context context) {
            System.out.println("clean up in mapper");
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("inside reduce method");
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(" Nullwritable value" + NullWritable.get());
                System.out.println("key inside reduce method" + key.toString());
                context.write(NullWritable.get(), values.next());
                // out.write(NullWritable.get(), values.next(), "/user/hadoop/"
                // + context.getJobID() + "/" + key.toString() + "/part-");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");

        Configuration configuration = getConf();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration);
        job.setJarByClass(DataValidation.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

    }

    private static Configuration getConf() {
        return new Configuration();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly over-ridden reduce method. Use this:

public void reduce(Key key, Iterable values,
                      Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException